# To put something out of order unintentionally

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language, phrase-choice

What verbs would you use to convey the idea of someone having broken/putting something out of order.

1. My car won't start! You /broke it/broke it down/put it out of order/ruined.
2. My computer doesn't work! You /broke it/broke it down/put it out of order/ruined.
3. My washing machine doesn't work! You /broke it/broke it down/put it out of order/ruined.
4. My washing machine doesn't work! You /broke it/broke it down/put it out of order/ruined.

Comment: Possibly 'sabotaged'?

Comment: I don't know. Can you break down a car?

Comment: *It won't work! You must have **damaged** it!*

Comment: No, we say that a machine _breaks down_, not that somebody breaks it down. _Sabotage_ is deliberate damage inflicted on a machine.

Comment: @Kate Bunting However, it's possible to break someone down emotionally for example? Right? I heard it today from an American speaker.

Comment: I suppose so, though it's not a common usage.

Answer (score 1):

If you knew for certain it was broken, you would say “you broke it”.

Other common expressions, given that you’ve already described the problem/state (i.e. the car won’t start), would be:

> My car won’t start - you’ve done something to it!

> My car won’t start - what have you done to it?!

This basically avoids the presumption inherent in saying “you broke it”, which is useful when you don’t know whether the thing would actually be considered broken or not; you’re simply stating the problem as observed, and then accusing them of being responsible for it.

Comment: I was told that it's not idiomatic to say "You broke my car".

Comment: It’s probably not, because people tend not to know what’s wrong with their cars, and “broke” is probably too generic for something so technical anyway. This is why I think you’d usually hear, “you’ve done something to it”, or, “it’s because of something you’ve done”.

Comment: The argument was that if you say it you would mean that you broke it into pieces which is improbable in reality.

Comment: No, “broke my car” wouldn’t be interpreted as having broken it into pieces. It might be viewed somewhat humourously given the great complexity of a car, perhaps similar to saying “you broke my house” or “you broke the world”.

Comment: I think "you broke my car" is okay. "My car is broken." "Oh, why?" "Sam broke it."